# Magento back-end running slow

Tags: php, apache, magento

We have a Magento website running on one of our linux servers. Running Php 5.6.17 no CGI on Apache 2.4.18

The Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 website has 1025m set in php.ini.

MageWorx Admin v1.1.1
Advanced Product Options v2.9.13
Extended Sitemap v3.1.2

Cache management settings are all enabled:
Layouts
Blocks HTML output
Translations
Collections Data
EAV types and attributes
Web Services Configuration
Web Services Configuration
Catalog Permissions cache
TM Full Page Cache

Database is running on MySQL 5.6.28 with a size of 1,99 gb. With over 19k products.

I hope you have enought information. Now the question:

What other options do i have to speed up the backend CMS sytem. It takes over a few minutes to add a new product. This Specific happens on the screen

New Attribute / Manage Attributes / Attributes / Catalog / Magento Admin.
It takes about 5 min when i press save.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l38y5.jpg

Comment: have multiple database instances for write procedures and replicate into the standard read database. you could also look for any observers that fire on product save and see if you can remove them or optimize them so that extraneous things don't happen.

Comment: also this post may help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/magento-enterprise-slow-product-save-w-and-wo-solr-integration

Comment: How often you update your stock , if not much you could consider developing an extension for cashing queries via Memcache or Redis, I also don't want to demoralize you but Magento is much slower than open cart , due to its core design, if your boss is really stuck with Magento then consider the caching solution, that's my2 cents.

Comment: We add/update a items on a daily basis.

Comment: No mention on the hardware, need fast hardware with plenty of memory, database on a separate system that's optimized for file IO and optimization of MySQL from real world collected statistics, not rule of thumb junk. Magento requires resources in order to run, it's a real resource hog.

Comment: Processor Name 7 X Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5670 @ 2.93GHz
Vendor ID GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz) 2926.000
Total Memory 10286792 kB
Mysql & Apache both on the same server.

Comment: I'd put this in, you will see instant improvement in managing the products, it's the reindexing that's the issue in a catalog that size. https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-asynchronous-reindex.html

Comment: I checked the Re-index settings and they are all set to Update on Save. Does that mean if i add an new product it waits on the re-index processes before i can continue?